# Xamarin Android - Dismiss DialogFragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I have looked on several different threads on how to dismiss a DialogFragment but nothing seems to work for me. I want to be able to close the DialogFragment when I switch to a new Activity from the click event that I have. I tried by using something like `this.Activity.Dismiss()` from the click event but also tried this from where I show the DialogFragment:

```
if (_exportFragment != null)
            {
                _exportFragment.Dismiss();
            }
```

But none of these seem to work.

**EDIT**

This is where I display the DialogFragment:

```
gridview.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args)
            {
                // DIALOG FRAGMENT
                FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                //Remove fragment else it will crash as it is already added to backstack
                Fragment prev = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("dialog");
                if (prev != null)
                {
                    ft.Remove(prev);
                }

                ft.AddToBackStack(null);

                // Create and show the dialog.
                _exportFragment = new VideoExportDialogFragment();
                _exportFragment.VideoCreationDate = VideoList[args.Position].CreationDate;
                //_exportFragment.
                _exportFragment.VideoPathFragment = VideoListPosition(args.Position);

                //_exportFragment.ThumbnailActivity = this;
                //Add fragment
                _exportFragment.Show(ft, "dialog");
                dismissLoader();
            };
        }

        private void dismissLoader()
        {
            if (_exportFragment != null)
            {
                _exportFragment.Dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is only Dismiss method, https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.DialogFragment.Dismiss()/

If dismissDialog() of your own method, post the code of it

Comment: Sorry, I edited now that was my own function but I also tried with Dismiss() and it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you post code on dialog fragment initialisation & dismiss?

Comment: I added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to close the DialogFragment when I switch to a new Activity from the click event that I have.

In this click event, you could find the `dialogFragment` that you want to close by using `FindFragmentByTag("dialog")` method, then you could use `_exportFragment.Dismiss()` to dismiss this `DialogFragment`. Code like this :

```
bt.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
     MyDialogFragment _exportFragment = (MyDialogFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("dialog");
     if (_exportFragment != null)
     {
           _exportFragment.Dismiss();
     }
     //StartActivity(you);
};
```